# Circular arc, integration

Tags: integration, circles

Using polar coordinates I am trying to integrate circular arc, but my end result is `7.138330888` and not `7.1416...`. What am I doing wrong?
[image]
$$r(\theta) = \sqrt{(2\cdot{sin}(\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{a}\cdot\theta)+2)^2+(2\cdot{cos}(\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{a}\cdot\theta)+2)^2}$$
$$Area=\frac12\int_0^a r^2 \, d\theta = \frac12\int_0^{0.6435...} (2\cdot{sin}(\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{0.6435...}\cdot\theta)+2)^2+(2\cdot{cos}(\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{0.6435...}\cdot\theta)+2)^2 \,d\theta = 7.138330888$$

Comment: The shaded region can be decomposed into a quarter-circle with radius $2$ and two triangles having base length $2$ and height $2$. It follows that the wanted area is $\pi+4=7.14159\ldots$

Comment: You are probably considering the circle arc as centered at the origin, while it is centered at $(2,2)$. Anyway, the use of integrals is absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio I know it can be done your way, but I need to integrate this curve some how using polar coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving the problem in the efficient way leads to an area equal to $\pi+4$. In the inefficient way, we have to compute $x^2+y^2$ where $(x,y)$ is the largest solution of $y=x \tan\theta$ and $(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2 = 4$, for $\theta\in\left[\arctan\frac{1}{2},\arctan 2\right]$. The area is so given by
$$ 2 \int_{\arctan\frac{1}{2}}^{\arctan{2}}\left(\cos\theta+\sin\theta+\sqrt{\sin(2\theta)}\right)^2\,d\theta $$
or, by the substitution $\theta=\arctan u$,
$$ 2\int_{1/2}^{2}\left(\frac{1}{1+u^2}+\frac{2\sqrt{2u}+4u+2u\sqrt{2u}}{(1+u^2)^2}\right)\,du.$$
The latter is quite a horrible integral, but it can be computed by partial fraction decomposition as
$$ \left[4\arctan(\sqrt{2u}-1)-\frac{4+2\sqrt{2u}(1-u)}{1+u^2}\right]_{1/2}^{2}=\pi+4. $$
The *inefficient way* leads to an interesting exercise in Calculus.